# Unknown Table After MySQL BEFORE INSERT Trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble inserting a row into a table after creating a trigger. I can insert the row just fine before I made the trigger, but after I made the trigger I'm not able to. It gives me an error saying that the 'LoadObservation' table doesn't exist. Could anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

```
CREATE TABLE `LoadObservation` (
  `sensor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `oid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sensor_id`,`oid`),
  CONSTRAINT `LoadObservation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sensor_id`) REFERENCES `LoadSensor` (`sensor_id`)
)

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER LoadMalfunction
BEFORE INSERT ON LoadObservation FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.sensor_id = LoadObservation.sensor_id  AND NEW.weight - LoadObservation.weight < 1000 
        THEN SET NEW.weight = LoadObservation.weight;
    END IF;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO LoadObservation(sensor_id, oid, Weight, timestamp) VALUES (350, 50001, 15000,
'2017-07-07 20:00:55');
```

Comment: What should `LoadObservation` in the trigger body refer to?

Comment: The LoadObservation table in my database.

Comment: Which doesn't make sense in the context you used it. You may [edit] your question and explain what the trigger is supposed to do.

Comment: for better understanding everthing that is NEW.weight  is a new row in the table LoadObservation and with this trigger you can acccess the data of the new row. like sticky bit said, it makes no sense and you should study some tutorail.

Comment: I will do more research on triggers before I add anything else to this question. Thank you for your help.